# How to convert a cython char* filled with 0x00 to non-empty byte array

Tags: python, json, cython, python-bytearray

Here is a cython fonction:

```
cdef struct my_struct_t:
    unsigned int a
    short b
    unsigned char[6] c

cdef void f_my_struct_t(int buff_size, const unsigned char* buf, list output):
    cdef:
        my_struct_t *arr = <my_struct_t *> buf
        list data = []

    for i in range(buff_size / sizeof(my_struct_t)):
        data.append(arr[i])

    output.append({
        "type": "my_struct_t",
        "data": data
    })
```

This function takes in parameter a buffer that contains a struct `my_struct_t` and format this struct into json format.

In C, `char*` is just an array of bytes.
In cython, it is considered as an array containing only ASCII characters.
So, if the first element is a `0x00` alias `'\0'`, it converts the byte array into `b''`. While if the char array contains only `0x00`, it should convert it as `b'000000'`.

The current result of this function is:

```
 {
    'type': 'my_struct_t',
    'data': [
      {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2,
        'c': b'' # Byte array should not be null
      }
    ]
  }
```

**How this dict could be parsed by `json.dumps(xxx, indent=4)` with en empty byte array?** Currently if fails because of this empty bytearray (or maybe just because there is a bytearray?).
Current error: `TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`

How to force cython to properly convert the char* into byte array?

Answer (score 0):

1. It isn't failing because it's empty - it's failing because it's bytes rather than a string. You need to convert it to a string by doing `bytes_value.decode("ascii")` (or whatever other encoding you may be using.
2. By default Cython treats char arrays as C strings and stops at the `\0` terminator. You can avoid this by slicing when you cast: `<bytes>arr.c[:6]`

   However, this you'll have to do this for the char array element manually. This won't work as part of Cython's automatic conversion from a C struct to a Python `dict` (which you're currently using).
3. A byte array contain only 0 values will convert into `b'\0\0\0\0\0\0'` (and not `b'000000'` like you claim). The ascii character `'0'` is not encoded with the numeric value `0`